# Why is compiler mis-stating namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, namespaces, compiler-warnings

Doing some C++ development after a good four years in Python, it appears I'm a little rusty.

I have three files in my very cut-down example (the actual code is much larger but this example still exhibits the problem). They are the code for the main file, and the code and header for a separate component that it will use:

```cpp
// xx.cpp:
#include "xx_store.h"
int main() {
    auto store = XX::XXStore();
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// xx_store.cpp:
#include "xx_store.h"
namespace XX {
    XXStore::XXStore() : m_map(XXEntries()) { }
    XXStore::~XXStore() { }
}
```

```cpp
// xx_store.h:
#include <map>
#include <string>
namespace XX {
    using XXEntry = struct {
        std::string m_value;
        bool m_found;
        uint32_t m_age_ms;
    };
    using XXEntries = std::map<std::string, XXEntry>;

    class XXStore {               // WHERE THE ERROR IS REPORTED.
    public:
        XXStore();
        ~XXStore();
    private:
        XXEntries m_map;          // THE APPARENT CAUSE.
    };
}
```

Now, when I compile that with `g++ --std=c++11 -o xx xx.cpp xx_store.cpp`, I get two warnings, one for each of the code files, but both referring to the same place in the header file:

```
xx_store.h:12:11: warning:
    ‘XX::XXStore’ has a field ‘XX::XXStore::m_map’ whose type uses
        the anonymous namespace [-Wsubobject-linkage]
        12 |     class XXStore {
           |           ^~~~~~~
```

Now I know from past experience that anonymous namespaces are per translation unit so it's unwise to do that in a header file that may be included by multiple code files.

But I can't see how the type of the `m_map` variable (which is `XXEntries`) is actually *in* the anonymous namespace. It's *clearly* inside the `namespace XX { ... }` area in the header file, as is the `XXEntry` type it depends upon. In fact, the warning even states that it's within the `XX::` part of the namespace.

Can anyone suggest why this warning may be happening? I know I can disable the warning but I'd rather not go down that path until I'm sure it's a false positive.

The environment is `Ubuntu 20.04` running `g++ 9.4.0`.

Comment: `using XXEntry = struct {` is a weird thing to do, `struct XXEntry {` should work better.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: hmm, that does indeed appear to have fixed it but I'm not sure why, given the alias-with-using is supposed to be modern C++ ?? In any case, if you make that an answer and provide at least a moderately viable reason why, I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: The `struct` is unnamed and it means its type is unique in each translation unit.

Comment: `using` is a modern replacement for `typedef`, but in this case you need neither, because in C++ (unlike C), `struct XXEntry { }` already creates a type.

Comment: @273K: Ah, that makes sense. It's the anonymous struct that we're aliasing, and it's different for each translation unit. I wonder whether `typedef struct { int x; } XXEntry;` (useless as it is in C++) would have the same issue since that structure is similarly unnamed.

Comment: `using XXEntry = struct {` is not something I've ever seen before. Why are you even doing that?

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili: I've used that method for things like real aliasing such as `using XXTime = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>` so it's both shorter and targeted to a functional type in my code (separate "types" based on functional use rather than identical underlying type). But I obviously went too far in using it to create (anonymous) and alias types in one go :-)

Comment: Answer, anyone? Anyone? Ferris?

Comment: @paxdiablo Oh, that's a different thing though, that's the intended use case. With an anonymous struct, that's very unorthodox.

Comment: @paxdiablo Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55878199/10147399

Comment: There's special magic that makes `typedef struct { int x; } XXEntry;` work (for better compatibility with C, I would guess). The term of art is [typedef-name for linkage purposes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef#typedef-name_for_linkage_purposes)